# Curried Functions are cached?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, ecmascript-next

> Curried functions gets cached by the compiler (*some guy*)

This component below has two buttons, one calls a function which returns the onClick handler, the other does the same, but inline.

According to my knowledge, both are doing the same thing, they are creating a new function `() => this.foo()` on each `render()` call. Someone said that the curried function version is cached and optimized by the compiler, so there is a benefit compared to the inline version. I think its the exact same thing and the guy who wrote this wanted to conceal an inline function with that expression.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  foo = () => console.log('fooo')

  getFunction = callback => {
    return () => callback();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.getFunction(this.foo)}>curried function</button>
      <button onClick={() => this.foo()}>inline function</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

I did some googling, but could't find a proof/disproof to the statement, what do you think guys?

Comment: I might be missing something, but... where's the currying here? Also, this is not JavaScript (nor es6) - you might want to tag also with [tag:jsx]?

Comment: In getFunction() ?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "In mathematics and computer science, currying is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument". Your `foo` is a nullary function, so I can't wrap my mind around how you think currying is being done. Are you using some alternative meaning of "currying"?

Comment: There is an es6 tag

Comment: There is. I am saying this is not ES6. `return <div>...</div>` is not in ES6 spec (but it is in JSX). Meanwhile, declaring methods using `=` is, AFAIK, neither ES6 nor JSX.

Comment: It is, you can call foo also like 'getFunction(foo)()'

Comment: Right its es2016 stage 1 I guess

Comment: Where is that statement from? Please cite its source! *(And also, who says "gecached"…)*

Comment: Oh its german, updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not doing the same thing; the `getFunction` one does call its callback without a `this` context. Of course, for the particular `foo` arrow function it doesn't matter at all.

Yes, both of these create a new function on every `render` call. The code of the respective closure would be cached, but the function object and its lexical context are not.

To avoid this, use the `foo` function itself (without any wrappers), which is created only once in the constructor:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.foo = (e) => console.log('fooo');
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.foo}>cached function</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```